# low overhead scheme to map u32 to a pointer

Tags: algorithm, linux-kernel

Basically I want to setup a map/hash/idr_type_of_thing that maps a unique u32 to a unique pointer value (unique within the current set of mappings). The guts of it is that the u32 is the physical address of a buffer as seen by a DMA engine and the pointer is the context blob about that buffer containing the buffer itself and other meta-data about the buffer. When I get some event from the DMA engine, it provides the u32 and from that I want to find the context blob for further processing (like release the DMA mapping, free buffer, etc). DMA engine can only return the u32 physical address. Is there some low-overhead fast scheme to do this mapping without coming up with some hash function that works well? BTW, any good hash functions that work well (no collisions?) for this type of mapping?

The total number of mappings that can exist at the same time is some fixed small number like say 512.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, There is `include/linux/rbtree.h`, the kernel's current red-black tree implementation that would seem the most intuitive.  (There is currently nothing generated under htmldocs for this, but also look at `Documentation/rbtree.txt`). A binary tree (of any sort) has O(log n) retrieval time.  However, it also has evils in its current form -- the key is still stored in the blob, and thus, a cache line of the blob is touched for each compare of the key.  I hope to fix this one day if somebody else doesn't do it first.

Other than that drawback, a red-black tree is a pretty efficient algo.

EDIT: Well, actually I can think of a number of other drawbacks, but it's probably the best in the kernel now.  If you feel especially unsatisfied with it, I will cheer you on as you implement something new!!!

Comment: Frankly, I would love to see somebody put in a more modern & cache-friendly algo for this. Judy trees is probably the most attractive, except for its patent issues.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find something O(1) and with no locking :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the pointer into the DMA memory, just before or just after the actual DMA buffer.
(Which one to use depends on your alignment requirements and whether you know the DMA buffer's size.)

Comment: Thanks. Wondering if you know of any rules regarding the use of cb in the skb. Comments indicate it is free to use by any layer but it is probably already used by upper layers (some uses appear to be for TCP and IP options) but there are probably many many more. Perhaps they expect the "state" to be preserved in the tx_completion callback...

Comment: Ask that as a new question wth proper tags (but you might want to read the comment in skbuff.h first).